# Почему не отрабатывает проверка сообщений? python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text=['Найти группу'])
async def func(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите номер группы")
    if(message.text == '7'):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели номер группы 7")
```

Comment: Что вы хотели написать? После того как человек написал "Найти группу", он должен ввести ее номер?

Comment: Да, пользователь вводит Найти группу, ему выдается сообщение     await message.answer("Введите номер группы"). И я хочу запустить проверку сообщение. Если 7, то соответствующий ответ. но я перешел с телебота на aiogram. Там чуть проще, а тут я что то путаю с синтаксисом. и ошибок не выдает, просто игнорирует сообщения пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В **Aiogram** существует **[FSM](https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/fsm/)**. Используйте её для того, чтобы переходить из действия 1 к действию 2

```
class UserStates(StatesGroup):
    find_group = State()

@dp.message_handler(text=['Найти группу'])
async def func(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Введите номер группы")
    await state.set_state(UserStates.find_group)

@dp.message_handler(UserStates.find_group)
async def func(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if(message.text == '7'):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели номер группы 7")
    await state.clear()
```

Comment: Я изучил FSM, все сделал согласно инструкции как Вы мне и выслали. Пишет ошибку TypeError: Filter must be callable and/or awaitable! - ошибка не гуглится. 
Смотрю что обьект должен быть вызываемым. Но что же ему не нравится?

Может ошибка синтаксиса? так как у меня версия aiogram 2*

Comment: https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-2-guide/fsm/ - тоже изучил, особо отличий я не нахожу.

Comment: await ставите перед сменой state?

Comment: да, ставил. Посмотрите ниже, чуть отредактировал, так сностнее смотрится?

Answer (score 0):

Решил еще проблему немного иначе:

```
class StateGroupExample(StatesGroup):
    wait_for_answer = State()

@dp.message_handler(text='Найти группу')
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(text='Введи номер группы')
    await StateGroupExample.wait_for_answer.set() 

@dp.message_handler(state=StateGroupExample.wait_for_answer)
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == '7':
        await message.answer(text='группа 7........')
    elif message.text == '6':
        await message.answer(text='группа 6........')
    else:
        await message.answer(text='Такой группы нет!')
    await state.finish()
```